# Frequency by rows over a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of 20 data frames of the following form:

```
    k    h   value
85 12 h=35 0.0401
86 11 h=34 0.0400
87 10 h=22 0.0405
88  9 h=32 0.0409
89  8 h=22 0.0414
90  7 h=19 0.0435
91  6 h=18 0.0443
92  5 h=17 0.0440
93  4 h=17 0.0445
94  3 h=16 0.0450
95  2 h=15 0.0450
96  1 h=17 0.0363
97  0 h=12 0.0152

[[2]]
    k    h   value
85 12 h=32 0.0019
86 11 h=29 0.0019
87 10 h=64 0.0019
.. .. ...  ...
.. .. ...  ...
```

What I want is to create a frequency table as a dataframe or matrix over the list of all data frames for every row (for every k), but I've no idea how to archieve that. So an output that tells me for every k the amount of different values of h. My idea was to merge all columns "h" in a new data Frame and then calculating the frequencies for every k, but that would be not the smartest way I think. The expected Output should look like this

```
 k   h=1  h=2  h=3 ....                     h=64
12 freq  freq  freq 
11
10
 9
 8
 7
 6
 5
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to `rbind` all these data frames instead of using a list and then get a frequency table?

Comment: the list results by lapplying over all my Input data Frames to get the data Frames in my example above

Comment: Yeah, so run `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` and turn your list of data frames in the question into one data frame, and then your solution is `with(combined_data, table(k, h))`.

Comment: How does `freq` relate to `value`, or are you ignoring `value`??

Comment: value should be ignored. I just want the frequencies of all possible "h"

Comment: How about `plyr::join_all(lst, by = "k", type="Full")`

Comment: @MKR it doesnt work :/ As a result I get only one of the two data frames

Comment: @Leo96 it should have combined rows from all data.frame with 3 columns. Finally one has to calculate frequency on that.

Comment: @Leo96 I think its worth sharing a toy sample data and expected output. We can try out solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr based solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4), h=c(1,2,1,2))
summarydf <- df %>% group_by(h) %>%
  summarise(count=n())
```

Also, if all the dataframes have the same structure, you can use rbind to combine them first.

Comment: I got a solution with plyr, that works as well. Thanks for the hint to rbind the dataframes: plyr::ldply(foo, rbind), table(foo$k,foo$h)